# How to change request method in Yii2 custom URL rules from GET to POST and others?

Tags: php, yii2

I am trying to work in RESTfull web services in `Yii2` using default controller. But the problem I faced is, I cannot send POST request with parameters.
Below is my code:

Url Manager rule in `web.php`

```
'urlManager' => [
        'class' => 'yii\web\UrlManager',
        // Disable index.php
        'showScriptName' => false,
        // Disable r= routes
        'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
        'rules' => array(
            ['pattern' => 'api/v1/auth/payment/<id:\d+>', 'route' => 'api/v1/auth/payment'],
            '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/view',
            '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
            '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
        ),
    ],
```

`AuthController.php` file this is inside `controller/api/v1/`

```
namespace app\controllers\api\v1;

use app\controllers\api\v1\components\ApiFunctions;
use Yii;
use yii\web\Controller;


class AuthController extends Controller
{
    public function actionPayment()
    {
        $id = Yii::$app->getRequest()->getQueryParam('id');
        json_encode($id);
    }

}
```

But when I send `GET` request to `http://{url}//api/v1/auth/payment/5` I get response as `5`. But I want to get that result when sending `POST` or any other methods.

So how can I achieve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me show you how i solve it [for my application](https://github.com/TNChalise/yii2-rest-api-Basic-Application-Template-).

A simple application structure i have constructed for basic application setup was.

------ app

------modules

----------api

-------------modules

----------------v1

-------------------controllers

-------------------models

-------------------etc

You can simply go through the application setup first.

Then  define verb filtering in every controller or sort it out by defining in a common class, as i have done [here.](https://github.com/TNChalise/yii2-rest-api-Basic-Application-Template-/blob/master/modules/api/modules/v1/controllers/UserController.php)

Then with the same rule you have defined in urlManager, you will able be to get the request query parameter.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Use

`'POST <controller:\w+>s' => '<controller>/create',`

See more http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-web-urlmanager.html

More **example** from documentation

```
[
    'dashboard' => 'site/index',

    'POST <controller:\w+>s' => '<controller>/create',
    '<controller:\w+>s' => '<controller>/index',

    'PUT <controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>'    => '<controller>/update',
    'DELETE <controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/delete',
    '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>'        => '<controller>/view',
];
```